# Spots on hardy kiwi leaves

Tags: diagnosis, leaves, pest-control

We have recently bought Ken's Red type of hardy kiwi ([Actinidia Arguta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Actinidia_arguta)) and we grow it on a balcony. Unfortunately, it has strange spots on leaves.

[image]
[image]

What could be the reason?